# call to a memeber function.. on string, how do i get past this error

Tags: php

creating a log in page where if a user is already logged in they are redirected to the home page, however upon execution I get the error code :

> call to a member function isloggiedin() on string

what am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php
include "H:\p3t\phpappfolder\public_php\FYP\includes\api\config\database.php";


if(User::is_loggedin()!="") 
{
    $user->redirect('home.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])) // line  11 where new error exists
{
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(User::login($user,$password))
    {
        $user->redirect('home.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $error = "Wrong Details !";
    }
}
?>
```

the following code may also help as it is my class.user.php file:

```
<?php
class USER
{
    private $db;

    function __construct($DB_con)
    {
        $this->db = $DB_con;
    }



    public function login($user,$password)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name=:username OR user_email=:password LIMIT 1");
            $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$user, $password));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                if(password_verify($password, $userRow['user_pass']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function is_loggedin()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function redirect($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

as you can see I have the function "isloggedin" so I don't understand why I am getting the error

after following the advice in the answer I was presented with the error message :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in H:\p3t\phpappfolder\public_php\FYP\includes\api\login.php on line 11

Comment: `$user` is clearly a string and not an object or an instance of the USER class. How could you think this would work?

Comment: In your method `login`, your code in `$stmt->execute...` would need to pass the password as the correct key as well - BUT you should learn to use [`password_hash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash)

Comment: The user class is never instantiated in your code, and as @JohnConde said, you assigned the string output of `$_POST['username']`. You can't use `$user` as both a class and a variable for username.

Answer (score 0):

`$user` is the string parameter, not a `User` object, so you can't use `$user->is_loggedin()`.

The `is_loggedin()` method doesn't use any class properties, so it can be a static method.

```
public static function is_loggedin()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['user_session']);
}
```

Then you can use

```
if (User::is_loggedin())
```

Also, you shouldn't set `$user` and `$password` before

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-login']))
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get passed the error however now I am faced with a syntax error which states the following: unexpected if on line 13 ( if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) )

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that, the problem could be on the line before it. Post the exact error message in the question.

Comment: BTW, the word is "past", not "passed".

Comment: thank you for the correction,  I have updated the question

Comment: That usually means you didn't terminate things properly on the previous line.

Comment: Like forgetting the `;` at the end of the previous statement.

Comment: I don't think that's the case because when I have tried to remedy the error for example adding a ";" the error remains the same, when I remove the if statement that is causing the error it is replaced by another error stating the else statement is unneccesary

Comment: Add the new code to the question, I can't tell what's wrong without seeing it.

Comment: please ignore my previous statement, you were right, thank you for the help again really appreciated